# making a game where a ball bounces of side of screen and doesen't

Tags: javascript, html, 2d-games

I am working on this code from a tutorial on Udemy where I am trying to make Pong. I am in the early stages and just want to have the ball bounce off the edge of a screen.
It doesn't though.
I think the problem might be where I define

```
ballspeedx = -ballspeedx
```

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600">
    
      </canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas;
    var canvasContext;
    var ballx = 50
    var ballspeedx = 12;

    window.onload = function() {
      var FPS = 80
      setInterval(function() {
        moveEverything();
        drawEverything();
      }, 10000 / FPS)

    }

    function moveEverything() {
      ballx = ballx + ballspeedx;
      if (ballx > 800) {
        console.log("GREATER THAT 800")
        ballspeedx = -ballspeedx
        ballspeedx = ballspeedx + ballspeedx

        console.log("Hello?")
      }
      if (ballx > 0) {
        ballspeedx = 5;
      }

    }

    function drawEverything() {
      ballx = ballx + 5;
      console.log(ballx)
      canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
      canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d')
      canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
      canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
      canvasContext.fillRect(0, 210, 20, 100);
      canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
      canvasContext.fillRect(ballx, 100, 10, 10);

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it doesn't bounce off the edge of the screen, what does it do instead?

Comment: You really should be using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of `setInterval` for animations.

Comment: It continues going right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the block

```
if (ballx > 0) {
   ballspeedx = 5;
}
```

If the ball is on the rightmost edge (800), it's still greater than zero. So even if you flip the velocity (which is what you're supposed to do), that automatically sets it to continue going further to the right. I changed your `moveEverything()` function to this and it worked fine:

```
function moveEverything() {
  ballx = ballx + ballspeedx;
  if (ballx > 800 || ballx < 0) {
    ballspeedx = -ballspeedx;
    ballx += ballspeedx;
  }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't move the ball in `drawEverything()`, that's just bad design.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work. Thanks a lot. also why is using DrawEverything() bad design?

Comment: It's not using DrawEverything() that's bad, it's the fact that you have `ballx = ballx + 5;`, which moves the ball INSIDE of DrawEverything(). DrawEverything() should draw and do nothing else, which makes it bad to move the ball inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
if (ballx > 0) {
    ballspeedx = 5;
}
```

to

```
  else if (ballx > 0) {
    ballspeedx = 5;
  }
```

I think you are setting the correct ballspeedx value then immediately dropping into the next if and overwriting it.